# How to set a page to be the background of another page in Microsoft Visio 2010?

Tags: microsoft-visio

As in cacoo.com, I want to set the background of Page-1 to be the content of Page-2 as in below snapshot.

Is it possible in Microsoft Visio 2010?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set this through `Page Setup`, which is accessible via `right-clicking` the page name tab in Visio 2010 and later or `File`->`Page Setup...`->`Page Properties`(tab) in prior versions.

1. First you have to set your `Page-2` as a `background page`, in the
   `Page Setup` dialog
2. Then for `Page-1` you have to `set Page-2 as the background page`.